# To constraint only one vector axis in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, constraints, unityscript

I m new to stackoverflow ,so hi guys!

And again i'm new to Unity too.I have a problem with constrainting my object.(Sorry for my english if it s not that good.)
I want to limit my player object but only at one axis.The Y is 0.0f and the Z is independent of the limitation.Can we do this job using MathF.clamp with rigidbody?If we can't , How can i solve this with typing C# rather than using Box & untick MeshCollider & adding collider. Thanks for advance :)

Comment: What components does your player object have? How is it moving? You need to provide more details about it, otherwise we can only guess at what the solution is.

Answer (score 1):

No code is needed. Look at Rigidbody's constraints.

> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html

Comment: Thanks  for your interest. it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you re right maybe i must be more specific. now my code is running .
the old and issued part was like--->

Hareket is Predefined value and the boundary is public Boundary boundary;

...

`GetComponent<Rigidbody>().Velocity=Hareket;
        LastZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.z;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = new Vector3
            (
                Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.x,boundary.xMin,
boundary.xMax),
                0.68f,
                Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.z,0f,
LastZ)
                );`

....

But i shouldn't have used the last part as`Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.z,0f,
LastZ)`
   But it should have been only the `LastZ` value.

And also to keep the rotation effect on the sphere the 
`GetComponent<Rigidbody>().Velocity=Hareket;` part should be `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()AddForce(Hareket);` 
...

thanks .